# What bulbs/globes fit the STANLEY 6-0766 socket, on a stock 1985 Honda TRX 250 4 wheeler?

Tags: bulbs

'What bulbs/globes fit the STANLEY 6-0766 socket, on a stock 1985 Honda TRX 250 4 wheeler?'
(I had a look in the headlight, & there's no bulb/globe in there at the moment) Doing a web search populates 'A7046H 12V 35W Bulb'. This model motorbike has a high/low switch, which I'd like to utilize. What are the options/What is compatible?
Thanks in advance!